# Implement AutoCorrect in a Quill editor

Tags: javascript, quill

I'd like to implement AutoCorrect in my Quill editor.

For example, when the user types the string `(c)` in their Quill editor, I'd like to replace it with the string `©`.

I'd like to use the same mechanism to replace straight quotes with curly quotes, to correct basic misspellings, and to automatically insert a new bulleted list when the user starts a new line with `*`, so I'm looking for an efficient mechanism that can be generalized around those use-cases.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [keyboard bindings](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/keyboard/) might be a good solution for the use cases you mention except for the "correct basic misspellings" one, since specific characters are expected to trigger the change: ), ', or space. At the moment the ) case will need to use shiftKey + 0, but once support is added for `event.key` that can be easier for different keyboards. There is already a [core implementation](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/develop/modules/keyboard.js#L250) for the automatic bullets except triggered by hyphen instead of asterisk so that may be worth looking at.

The correct basic misspellings, unless scoped extremely narrowly, seems far more complex than all the others combined. Not sure there is a suggestion here without more details on scope.

Comment: Thanks! These suggestions are perfect... Don't get distracted by "correcting basic misspellings"... I actually already have a mature application with support for these features, ([shaxpir.com](https://shaxpir.com)), which is based on CKEditor. Now, I'm switching to Quill, and I'm just trying to re-implement the functionality of my existing CKE plugins, so I was looking for a mechanism to observe and react to keypresses :)